# Total Progress over entire bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, pv, whiptail

EDIT FOR CLARITY :

say I have the following script (let's posit pv and curl are already installed) :

<sub>(that currently runs under ubuntu but that I plan to make POSIX-compliant so that it may run on more linux ditributions)</sub>

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt install vlc
mkdir -p ~/.steam/compatibilitytools.d
PROTONVERSIONNUMBER=$(curl -v --silent https://api.github.com/repos/popsUlfr/Proton/releases 2>&1 | grep "tag_name" | head -n 1 | cut -f4,4 -d"\"")
REPLACING=$(curl -v --silent https://api.github.com/repos/popsUlfr/Proton/releases 2>&1 | grep "target_commitish" | head -n 1 | cut -f4,4 -d"\"" | sed "s/[^_]\+/\L\u&/g")
PROTONVERSION=${REPLACING/_G/-6_G}
PROTONNAME=$PROTONVERSION"_"${PROTONVERSIONNUMBER##*-}
wget https://github.com/popsUlfr/Proton/releases/download/$PROTONVERSIONNUMBER/$PROTONNAME.tar.xz
pv $PROTONNAME.tar.xz | tar xp -J -C ~/.steam/compatibilitytools.d
rm $PROTONNAME.tar.xz
```

I get three progress bars, these progress bars seem very beautiful to me :

<sub>the way they're accurate and stuff, I dunno call me a weirdo</sub>

### QUESTION

How do I utilize the power of these three seperate progress bars to form one continuous progress bar that respects currents progress bar "speeds" of the underlying "true" progress bars?

Comment: You mention some concerns about the availability of `pv`, but do not seem to have the same concerns regarding the availability of `whiptail`, `apt`, `bash`, `sudo`, or `wget`. Do you have portability constraints at all? What does your "every OS" mean?

Comment: well ok my script is actually more robust then the barebones example above, I actually have a huge if else going over almost all possible linux distros and later down case switches change for example `sudo` and `apt` to their equivalents. maybe I should edit my post to specify that I intend for it to work on all distros but start by getting it to work on ubuntu first, for which `whiptail` and `wget` comes prepakaged but `pv` not. That being said I haven't entirely excluded working with pv, it seems quite powerfull and might be worth a temporary install as part of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample piece of code that demonstrates how you can have multiple sections of "work" all updating the same progress meter. The Whiptail gauge is attached to the script's file descriptor 3, so that it can be updated at any point during the script. (The gauge exits automatically when the script ends, or when FD 3 is explicitly closed.)

```
#!/bin/bash
#
pid=
tmpd=

tidyUp()
{
    # Clean up when we're done
    exec 3>&-
    [[ -n "$tmpd" ]] && rm -rf "$tmpd"
}
trap 'ss=$?; tidyUp; exit $ss' 1 2 15


updateGauge()
{
    local percent="$1" message="$2"
    printf "XXX\n%d\n%s\nXXX\n" $percent "$message" >&3
}


# Create the FIFO for communicating with the whiptail gauge
tmpd=$(mktemp --tmpdir --directory "wt.XXXXXXXXXX")
mkfifo "$tmpd/fifo"

# Start up the whiptail gauge and associate FD 3 with its status
whiptail --title 'Progress meter' --gauge 'Starting examples' 6 50 0 <"$tmpd/fifo" &
exec 3>"$tmpd/fifo"

# Real code starts here
percent=0

for example in 1 2 3
do
    updateGauge $percent "Getting example $example"
    sleep 3    # wget something

    percent=$((percent + 20))
done

for another in 4 5
do
    updateGauge $percent "Doing work for another example $another"
    sleep 2    # do some work

    percent=$((percent + 20))
done

# Done
tidyUp
exit 0
```

Comment: that's a no, there are two problems with this, one, the bar doesn't move between steps, the point of my question was "how could I **benefit** from existing progress bars?" not "how could I disregard them?" the second issue is that while you do get to see wget's progress bar on top, the display is broken : https://imgur.com/Q7Wod9N and either way I'm sure whiptail's intended behavior is to only have whiptail visible. I think i'll try with pv instead.

Comment: 1. As written it does move between steps. If it doesn't work for you, how are you calling it?

Comment: 2. You'd run `wget -q` so that the whiptail progress meter was the only thing showing. I addressed your seemingly fundamental "_all I want is to have a progress bar present from start to finish of my script_". Pretty definite to me.

Comment: I dunno you try it : https://pastebin.com/2YZRgu4B I get  visual glitching all over the terminal console, it's impossible to see what's going on.

Comment: here's a new version where I fixed the extra outputs : https://pastebin.com/ikrp7AN2 as you can see, the progress bar of whiptail jumps from 0 to 20 ect... i can see why if I remove pv from the tar opperation whiptail would have nothing to go off of but for the wget it has no progress either

Comment: I understand what you mean now by "the progress bar is indeed moving", you're just echoing a random 20% increase spread out over the duration of the task. increaseing the update frequency could combat how inacurate the progress bar currently is but never match simply utilising the actuall progress percentage from `wget`, `install`, `tar` and so on operations which is what I suggested doing in my opening post, are you telling me there's absolutely no way to do such a thing?

Comment: nope : https://pastebin.com/9EfQBBUp it just makes the whole thing slower, for a side-by-side comparison, run my original script without whiptail : https://pastebin.com/MjgJd6we, ...this version is done in just under one minute

Comment: Looking at your pastebins [ikrp7AN2](https://pastebin.com/ikrp&AN2) and [9EfQBBUp](https://pastebin.com/9EfQBBUp) you don't seem to have understood the point of the example. You don't seem to need the loops in the real world as you're just repeating the same work over and over. Just use `updateGauge` to update the gauge that runs for the duration of the demonstration script.

Comment: actually I think I understand annother reason why this is a bad approach : the for loops run this code you were supposed to get progress on several times...

Comment: This is a demonstration of how to solve your requested issue. Not a complete solution to a problem you hadn't shown us.

Comment: I don't see how repeating the task has any use. my bash script, as most bash script is sequential, not procedural. shell is not some sort of crontab nor is it C++. there are certain tools for certain things, in my case I made it pretty clear what my script did, it downloaded : WGET and it installed : APT INSTALL I don't see how one could assume from the use of such commands that this was going to be anything other than sequential.

Comment: "_I don't see how repeating the task has any use_". It has no use other than as an illustration. It's simply an example piece of code. In your code you'd call `updateGauge` after each step.

Comment: yeah so if you read my opening post right at the top I begin by criticizing human-feeding values to whiptail vs a *potential hypothetical* machine-feeding values to whiptail. from the turn this is taking I guess I'm to gather whiptail simply cannot receive any other sort of input other than an int. it can't be piped to the same way a great number of commands such as grep/cat/cut/find/sed... ect ect ect can. Also retrieving via sed or other the percent from the current verbose would not work / is too hard, just say that. but don't pretend I asked for B when clearly I asked for A.